# bootstrap: prevent background redraw in a fluid site popping a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

The way the bootstrap modals seem to work is that they hide the overflow-y of the body, thereby removing it's vertical scroll-bar in Microsoft environments, and changing the width of the body's due to the widening of the view-port. This triggers the fluid site to redraw to fit the view-port, and THEN the modal is able to pop up and dim the background with a scroll-bar dedicated to the modal....

I've seen some other topics similar to this but nothing that addresses it directly:

Is it possible, if using a 100% fluid (fills whole view-port) website design with modals in bootstrap, to prevent the page in the background from redrawing before the modal background dims and the modal flies in?

There's the slightest annoying widening and then shrinking of the background site when that scrollbar is swapped in and out for the incoming modal.

This is the example page for bootstrap's modals... notice that the background site DOES NOT resize when the modal flies in because this page is not a fluid design. If the same modal is popped over a site that is responsively stretched to fit the whole viewport, that hiding of the body overflow causes the whole page to re-render with the extra width (windows only! Mac's proprietary scroll style doesn't deform)

Comment: This is not only a bootstrap problem and I would be interested to investigate. Most of the time it stems from paddings and borders on html and body elements. Some example, maybe on jsfiddle, would be nice.

Comment: I was just trying to make a fiddle, but anything that involves the "BODY" tag seems to be a bit tough to work with in JS fiddles??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/u7LUU/ - here it works just fine. No resizing when dialog opens. But on the http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals you can see that scroll bar disappears for a split second, because overflow-y was affected. I believe there is a way to solve it via css/options but I did not dig deep enough yet.

Comment: I don't think it's the same because the WINDOW changes width in my problem, which doesn't seem to happen in the fiddle...